# JDBCTempalte RowMapper to read jsonb column in postgres table

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, rowmapper

I am reading the Postgres table using the JDBCTemplate, which has the below schema:

> orderid|order_name|features|extra_features|

orderid: integer
order_name: text
features: josnb
extra_features: jsonb

**Order DTO:**

```
public class Order{
  private Integer orderid;
  private String orderName;
  List<Features> features;
  List<ExtraFeatures> extraFeatures;
       ....

   getter & setter   
}
```

**Feature DTO:**

```
public class Features{
  private String featureName:
  private String featureValuel
}
```

Now, while executing the **SELECT * FROM public.orders** query, I am writing the rowMapper like below:
`jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM public.orders", new OrderRowMapper())`

**RowMapper**

```
public class OrderRowMapper implements RowMapper<Order>{
  @Override
  public Order mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{
     Order order = new Order();
     order.setOrderid(rs.getInt("orderid"));
     order.setFeatures()// how to read jsonbcolumn?
  }
}
```

I am able to set all the values except the jsonb column, I don't know how to implement RowMapper for that, please help.

Comment: Did you try `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Features> features = objectMapper.readValue(rs.getString("features"), new TypeReference<List< Features >>(){});`

Comment: Your solution is working. (Y)

Comment: `ObjectMapper` is threadsafe, so you can reference it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class OrderRowMapper implements RowMapper<Order>{
  private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public Order mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{

     List<Features> features = objectMapper
          .readValue(rs.getString("features"), 
                     new TypeReference<List<Features>>(){});
     Order order = new Order();
     order.setOrderid(rs.getInt("orderid"));
     order.setFeatures()// how to read jsonbcolumn?
  }
}
```